# Maxima: Using makeset with a given set

Tags: set, maxima

Using the computer algebra system Maxima I try to do a very simple set operation: given a set A of sets and a set a, I'd like to build the set of the union of all elements of A and a.
So for example let be A={{1,2}, {3,4}, {}} and a={0,97}. The set I am searching for is then {{0,97,1,2}, {0,97, 3,4}, {0,97}}.

Well, I suppose the easiest way would be by using makeset:

```
makeset(union(a,x), [x], A);
```

Unfortunately this returns an error:

```
"$union": argument must be a set; found: x
```

Well the problem is as far as I have understood that the third argument of makeset has to be a list of lists or a set of lists. From the maxima documentation:

```
(%i5) makeset (sin(x), [x], {[1], [2], [3]});
(%o5)               {sin(1), sin(2), sin(3)}
```

Because I want x to be a set the third argument has to be a set of lists of sets in my case. But A is given and I have no idea how to transform it in an easy way. Probably I could to everything in a loop or so, but the problem seems quite simple to me and I'm wondering if there is really not better way.

Any ideas?

**Update:** I just had an idea for a work-around, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. I managed to bring A into the correct form by using cartesian_product:

```
makeset(union(a,x), [x], cartesian_product(A));
```

Still I get the same error: x should be a set. Well it is a set, since A is a set of sets. If I write {x} instead of x, everything is working as expected, but I want to join x with a not {x} with a... I think this might be a actually a bug in Maxima.

**Update 2:** Same problem with lists:

```
makeset(append(x, [a]), [x], full_listify(cartesian_product(A)));
```

Returns error:

```
append: argument must be a non-atomic expression; found x
```

**Update 3:** Refer also to the conversation at [Maxima's bug tracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3439895&group_id=4933&atid=104933).

**Solution:**
To make things easier for readers of this question, here the solution (from Stavros' answere and my first update) an example with both workarounds combined:

```
(%i1) A : {{a,b},{c},{d}};
(%o1) {{a,b},{c},{d}}

(%i2) makeset('(union(x, {new1, new2})), [x], cartesian_product(A));
(%o2) {{a,b,new1,new2},{c,new1,new2},{d,new1,new2}}
```

Answer (score 2):

makeset, unlike makelist, evaluates its arguments, which is a poor design.  Sorry about that. There is a workaround for this:

```
makeset('(union(x)), '[x], {[{1}]});
```

but we'll fix this for future versions.

Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

```
    -s
```

PS I think you'll get better response on Maxima issues from the Maxima mailing list  than from StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following might be simpler.

```
A : {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {}};
a : {0.97};
map (lambda ([x], union (x, a)), A);
 => {{0.97}, {0.97, 1, 2}, {0.97, 3, 4}}
```

Sorry for the late reply. Leaving this here in case someone comes across it.